# HQL query using JOIN returns incomplete results

Tags: java, hibernate, join, hql

I have 2 tables, Book and Author, joined in a Many-To-Many relationship by table BookHasAuthor. The BookHasAuthor table is necessary since the relationship itself also has some other data inside. Both Book and Author have the relationship declared like this:

```
// Book.java
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<BookHasAuthor> authors = new HashSet<BookHasAuthor>(0);
```

What I want is to query for a specific Book, by id for instance, but fetching all of their relations at the same time. That way I can serialize the resulting Book object in a JSON and return it in a Response, after the Hibernate session has been closed.

Suppose that the database has 2 books with 3 authors each. Once the Query object has been created and the parameters set, I call `list()` to get the array of results. The problem is that my query attempts so far have only returned either 3 copies of the same Book, each with a "authors" array containing one entry, or a single Book object with just one of the authors. While I don't understand the second behavior, the first one is what I would expect using simple SQL, but the main reason I'm using HQL is precisely to abstract myself from having to merge all the results. So far, I've not found the correct way to query for one Book getting all of its Authors in the array.

These are the queries I've tried so far:

```
SELECT item FROM Book item JOIN item.authors WHERE item.id = 1
```

This returns 3 Books, each of them with a different Author in the "authors" array. Using INNER, LEFT JOIN or JOIN FETCH produced no change.

```
SELECT item FROM Book item WHERE item.id = 1
```

This returns 1 Book with an "authors" array with just 1 author.

I feel like I'm missing something really stupid here, but I can't understand what it is. Any advice?

EDIT: Just to clarify, I've created a new project, redone everything in the same fashion, and get the result that I expected, so maybe the problem I'm facing here has nothing to do with what I think. Any ideas on what may be causing this problem are most welcome.

Comment: Looks like you're actually using the JPA API here, not Hibernate directly. The tags are a bit off. As such if you're using a JPA 2.1 compatible version of Hibernate, you can use an [entity graph](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/) to not have to meddle with fetch joins. But that is not the question asked so I'll leave this as a comment

Comment: As to the question itself: what happens when you do a `left join fetch` ? (because you do want to do a join fetch, not a regular join)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Using LEFT JOIN FETCH throws the same results as a regular JOIN FETCH. I've ended up making separate queries for the relationship elements, so that my colleagues can continue working, but I haven't been able to pinpoint what is happening here.